# Getting this error in next js 13 app router “Module not found: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'”

Tags: node.js, next.js, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to convert mp4 to mp3 using the npm package 'fluent-ffmpeg’, in the express application it is working fine but not in NextJS 13, And even after removing the node_modules folder, package-lock.js and doing "npm install" again, it still didn't work. Does anyone have a solution for this?

This error is coming in the console.

```
> my-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.2
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env.local

<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/next isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/next isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
 ✓ Ready in 2.2s
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-musl isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-arm64-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-musl isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-darwin-x64 isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-gnu isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
 ⨯ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js:1:48
Module not found: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/api/new/route.js
 ○ Compiling /not-found ...
(node:3236) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
 ⨯ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js:1:48
Module not found: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/api/new/route.js
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/next isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
 ⨯ ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js:1:48
Module not found: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/api/new/route.js
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-musl isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-darwin-x64 isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-musl isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-gnu isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-arm64-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-ia32-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-arm64-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-musl isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-musl isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-darwin-x64 isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-x64-gnu isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy/webpack.FileSystemInfo] Managed item /Users/creative_aamir/Documents/My Website Projects /nextjs apps/testing-fluent-ffmpeg/node_modules/@next/swc-linux-arm64-gnu isn't a directory or doesn't contain a package.json (see snapshot.managedPaths option)
```

I also tried creating the webpack.config.js file in the root directory of the project but it did not work

`<`

```
import webpack from 'webpack'

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.FLUENTFFMPEG_COV': JSON.stringify(false),
    }),
  ],
};
```

`>`

This is my src/app/api/new/route.js file code

```
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg'
var command = ffmpeg()

export function GET(){

    command.input('mp4/video.mp4')
    
    .save('converted/audio.mp3')

    return NextResponse.json('Done')
}
```

This is next.config.js file

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is package.js file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "next": "14.0.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0"
  }
}
```

How to fix this error?